# SharePoint 2016 3 Tier Farm Installation Procedure

Tags: sharepoint-server

How do you build a 3-tier SharePoint Server farm?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has built great documentation you can easily find by searching for 'SharePoint 2016 installation'.

You can find the base of the documentation at [Install SharePoint Server 2016 across multiple servers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948(v=office.16).aspx). I would suggest reading through that process. That said, at a minimum you need two SharePoint servers. You can use the Custom MinRole on both or use the per-defined MinRoles of DC+FE and App+Search (when using the November 2016 PU or higher). Since you may be new to SharePoint, I would suggest using the per-defined MinRoles.